# Authenticate Oracle Database with Active Directory Users

Tags: oracle, authentication, active-directory, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect to Oracle Database 11gR2 with the users from Active Directory. Can I be pointed to some good links from where I can get this information.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go it worked for us. Good luck.

http://ilmarkerm.blogspot.com/2010/08/authenticate-database-user-against.html